# Oracle SQL count and group by multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle, count, grouping

I am able to get the data merging two tables to get the following table.

```
+------------+------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| Group Name | Type | Manger | Status | ControlOne | ControlTwo |
+------------+------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| Group A    |    1 |      1 | finish |          2 |          2 |
| Group A    |    2 |      1 | open   |          0 |          2 |
| Group A    |    1 |      1 | finish |          0 |          0 |
| Group A    |    1 |      2 | finish |          2 |          0 |
| Group B    |    1 |      1 | open   |          2 |          0 |
| Group B    |    1 |      2 | open   |          2 |          2 |
| Group B    |    2 |      2 | open   |          0 |          2 |
| Group B    |    2 |      1 | finish |          0 |          0 |
| Group B    |    1 |      1 | open   |          2 |          0 |
+------------+------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Now I need to get the total counts based on GroupName/ Type and Manager to have the output for each group in the following format:

```
+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Group Name | Type |                 Manager1Finish                  |                Manager1Open                |        Manager2Finish        |        Manager2Open        |
+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Group A    |    1 | 2(count of finish by Group A, manager1, type 1) | 0(count of open Manager1, Type 1, Group A) | 1(count of finish Manager 2) | 0(count of open manager 2) |
| Group A    |    2 | 0                                               | 1                                          | 0                            | 0                          |
+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Could you please help to how to achieve this?

Comment: You could try using window functions of oracle like `count(*) over (partition by some_column)` see [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/count-analytic-function) for more details

Answer (score 3):

Try with CASE WHEN:

```
  SELECT GroupName,
         TYPE,
         COUNT (CASE
                   WHEN     Manager = 1
                        AND status = 'Finish'
                   THEN
                      1
                END)
            AS Manager1Finish,
         COUNT (CASE
                   WHEN     Manager = 1
                        AND status = 'Open'
                   THEN
                      1
                END)
            AS Manager1Open,
         COUNT (CASE
                   WHEN     Manager = 2
                        AND status = 'Finish'
                   THEN
                      1
                END)
            AS Manager2Finish,
         COUNT (CASE
                   WHEN     Manager = 2
                        AND status = 'Open'
                   THEN
                      2
                END)
            AS Manager2Open
    FROM tablename
GROUP BY GroupName, TYPE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select [group], [type],
sum(case when manager=1 and status='finish' then 1 else 0 end) as m1finish,
sum(case when manager=1 and status='open' then 1 else 0 end) as m1open,
sum(...etc...)
from mytable
group by [group],[type]
```